# Python3.x: Variable Assignment for Different Cases

Tags: python, variables, if-statement, variable-assignment

I am attempting to assign different values to a variable depending on another variable. I have used `if...else` statements to do so. I am wondering if there is a more efficient/simpler way to accomplish this.

I am excluding lots of my code. I am analyzing data sets line by line where `column[3]` can be any number.

My code:

```
byte_3 = format(column[3], 'b').zfill(8)
alarm = int(byte_3[1:8], 2)
if byte_3[0] == '1':
    print_string += 'Alarm '
        if alarm == 0:
            stat = 'Voltage Dropout'
        elif alarm == 1:
            stat = 'Voltage Restored'
        elif alarm == 2:
            stat = 'Probe Started'
        elif alarm == 3:
            stat = 'Probe Completed'
        elif alarm == 4:
            stat = 'Cashbox Removed'
        elif alarm == 5:
            stat = 'Cashbox Restored'
    print(print_string + stat)
```

I would like for `stat` to change depending on the value assigned to `alarm`. Is it possible to accomplish this in a different fashion? The majority of the values assigned to `alarm` will be whole integers in 1-26 where each individual integer will change the assignment of `stat` i.e. if `alarm` is 0, I expect `stat` to be `Voltage Dropout` or if `alarm` becomes 4 I expect `stat` to be `Cashbox Removed`

Comment: Use a dictionary: `{0: 'Voltage Dropout', 1: 'Voltage Restored', ...}`.

Comment: You could also use a list `['Voltage Dropout', 'Voltage Restored', ...]`.

Comment: Rather than add a new answer, there must be a decent dupe for this that goes into some detail? I can find some but they're not covering it in great detail

Comment: Let me know if you find a dupe. Like you said, the ones I could find were not very detailed. Also, was not quite sure what to search for.

Comment: Just replace all your `if` and `elif` with a single line of `stat = my_dict.get(alarm, "not found")` and define `my_dict` beforehand like I did in my first comment e.g. `my_dict = {0: 'Voltage Dropout', 1: 'Voltage Restored', ...}`. I'm just looking for the canonical dupe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some answers brought up dictionaries, but it sounds like you want a little more in-depth explanation, which hopefully I can provide. Dictionaries are similar to lists, except you define a key and a value for each element in the dictionary. Then you can retrieve the value given the key. In your case, it would look something like

```
alarm = int(byte_3[1:8], 2)
stat_dictionary = {0:'Voltage Dropout',1:'Voltage Restored',2:'Probe Started',3:'Probe Completed',4:'Cashbox Removed',5:'Cashbox Restored'}
if byte_3[0] == '1':
    print_string += 'Alarm '
    print(print_string+stat_dictionary[alarm]
```

You could replace the stat_dictionary with a list and have the same function, but a dictionary is, imo, more clear.